# AD Recycle bin is enabled but no objects are in it?

Tags: active-directory

Sometime ago I enabled the active directory recycle bin using PowerShell. At the time I knew this to be working because of the following results:

```
Get-ADOptionalFeature -filter * |  select Name,FeatureScope,ObjectClass,RequiredForestMode | fl

Name               : Recycle Bin Feature
FeatureScope       : {ForestOrConfigurationSet}
ObjectClass        : msDS-OptionalFeature
RequiredForestMode : Windows2008R2Forest
```

My forest is set correctly

```
Get-ADForest | select -expand forestmode
Windows2008R2Forest
```

So everything appears to be in check there as well. However in testing deleting both users and containers I am unable to find them in order to recover those objects. The only thing that ever shows up is the deleted container itself

```
Get-ADObject -SearchBase "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=ba,DC=net" -Filter "*" -includeDeletedObjects

Deleted           : True
DistinguishedName : CN=Deleted Objects,DC=BA,DC=NET
Name              : Deleted Objects
ObjectClass       : container
ObjectGUID        : 4d59a6f2-eff1-494c-9e9a-a1731f19ac4b
```

From [what I can tell from looking at other tutorials about setting this up](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/the-active-directory-recycle-bin-in-windows-server-2008-r2/) that *should* be showing up. For me though, there should be other objects there that have been deleted over the past couple of weeks.

I am running my tests as a Enterprise Admin user. Searching for "recycling bin" and "active directory" leads me to other users that have similar issues but most of them are addressed by either actually enabling the feature or being at a lower forest level. In my case both are correct. Not sure what I am doing wrong here or assuming.

A fact that is quite possibly related is that I cannot see this "Deleted Objects" container from ldp.exe either as per [this guide I was using for comparison](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1374789&seqNum=4). The last step to see the container being:

> Expand the forest root domain in the console tree, as shown in Figure 8. Double-click the "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=Domain,DC=local" node, where DC=Domain,DC=local is the distinguished name of your forest root domain.

From that same page another PowerShell test shows results that contradict my problem as stated:

```
Get-ADObject -ldapFilter:"(msDS-LastKnownRDN=*)" -IncludeDeletedObjects
```

When I run that command I get *some* of the *user accounts and groups* that I was removing while testing. According to [this page on TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57882dc4-98c3-441d-a520-20f50640ce42/msdslastknownrdn-in-windows-server-2012-with-disabled-recycle-bin?forum=winserverDS) forums though that means the the bin is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You are at the correct Forest Level, but the query you are using to verify if the Recycle Bin is enabled is not correct. The 'Deleted Objects' container exists whether or not the Recycle Bin is enabled or not. If not enabled, then it holds the tombstoned objects with limited attributes, and if it is enabled, the deleted objects maintain their attributes for the lifetime of the object.

Use the following to verify that the Recycle Bin is actually enabled:

```
$RecycleBin = Get-ADOptionalFeature -Filter {Name -eq "Recycle Bin Feature"}
```

(True is not enabled, False is enable)

```
"[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($RecycleBin.EnabledScopes)"   # Without quotes
```

When you run the `Get-ADOptionalFeature -Filter {Name -eq "Recycle Bin Feature"}` command, if the EnabledScopes attribute is empty {}, then it is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question now, but for me the issue was running the `Get-ADObject` command from a non-administrative PowerShell. Could be obvious to some, but the fact that it returned a few entries from a non-admin shell threw me off.

In any case, after opening PowerShell as an admin I now see thousands, like I'd expect for our busy domain.